# Standard Toad template for formatting Oracle PL/SQL code?

Tags: oracle, plsql, formatting, toad

For a long time, I have used Red Gate to format my T-SQL code, and I have it set to something pretty readable and I always just accept it (saved many years of my life) and move on.

I've been fooling with it for an hour and I cannot get Toad (10.5.1.3) to format some pretty big views and procedures/packages anything near reasonable.  I like comma prefixed lists and on separate lines, but not for simple functional operators like NVL(), DECODE(), TO_NUMBER(), TO_CHAR(), which Toad is expanding vertically into a real mess.  I just want something clean...

Anyone have a good template they use for Toad for Oracle they'd be willing to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the previous dev had it all messed up - I reset each pane to defaults and then simply changed to leading commas and 160 char line length and it's much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can always adapt Toads Formatter Settings in

```
View -> Toad Options -> Files -> Formatter
```

Also Toad breaks your code into a new line if the line character limit is hit. Default this is set to `78` (`80` for the line `margin`).
Increase these values to prevent the vertical mess.